# how to use multipart/form-data in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) 
@Path("/uploadFile")
public POSResponse singleSave(@FormDataParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        Response response = new Response();
        String fileName = null;
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream buffStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("d:\\" + fileName)));
                buffStream.write(bytes);
                buffStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else {

        }
        return response;
}
```

when i hit this api then i got the error "415: Unsupported Media Type"
this means not supported header.I want to load file from ARC to controller.

and my console:

> A message body reader for Java class org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile, and Java type interface org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryP1d7Atv9FO9wU301 was not found.
>       The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
>       */* ->
>         com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
>         com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
>         com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
>         com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
>         com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
>         com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
>         com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider

i have add some maven dependency in pom.xml file.

My pom file:

```
<!-- multipart file dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring MVC. You are using jersey annotation and try to mix that with Spring MVC annotations... That is never going to work. Either use jersey or spring mvc, don't mix them in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the code which you have written but this how i did it in spring-mvc

Use case:  uploading Images

1. Add a bean definition in our web application's context configuration file 
   (DispatcherServlet-context.xml) for CommonsMultipartResolver,
   as follows:

   ```
   <bean   id="multipartResolver"  
           class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
           <property   name="maxUploadSize"    value="10240000"/>
   ```
2. Add dependency to pom.xml
   enter Group Id as commons-fileupload, Artifact Id  as commons-fileupload, Version as 1.2.2; select Scope as compile; and click on the OK button.
3. Similarly, add one more Group Id dependency as org.apache.commons, Artifact 
   Id as commons-io, Version as 1.3.2; select Scope as compile; click on the OK 
   button; and save the pom.xml file
4. Add a reference to
   `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` with the 
   corresponding setters and getters in the java class the defines the file as a property as follows:

   ```
   @JsonIgnore
   private MultipartFile productImage;
   @XmlTransient
   public MultipartFile getProductImage() {
       return productImage;
   }

   public void setProductImage(MultipartFile productImage) {
       this.productImage = productImage;
   }
   ```
5. In the jsp where the file is to be uploaded use the following tag
6. Set the enctype attribute to multipart/form-data in the form tag as 
   follows in the jsp

Note: I am using spring form tag libraries

```
<form:form  modelAttribute="newProduct" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

7. Add the following code to the controller

   ```
    public String processAddNewProductForm(@ModelAttribute("newProduct") @Valid Product productToBeAdded,  BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
           if(result.hasErrors())  {
               return  "addProduct";
           }


           MultipartFile productImage = productToBeAdded.getProductImage();

           String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

               if (productImage!=null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {
                  try {
                   productImage.transferTo(new File(rootDirectory+"resources\\images\\"+productToBeAdded.getProductId() + ".png"));
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                   throw new RuntimeException("Product Image saving failed", e);
              }
              }



           productService.addProduct(productToBeAdded);
           return "redirect:/products";
       }
   ```

****Prerequisites****

spring project has been setup correctly, wiring is done

few annotations and lines of code are specific to my project and may not be totally relevant

Comment: 5 . <div class="col-lg-10">
      <form:input id="productImage" path="productImage" type="file"
       class="form:input-large" />
     </div>